# How to make an API to interact with my app

Tags: java, android, api

How can I make an online server to access API's and handle requests? Then how can I have my android app access this online server to make requests?

I have an android app that I am building for a school project. This app will need to use multiple APIs to gather information to display to the user. However I don't want to allow people to decompile to source code and take my API keys. My plan is to build an online application that will do all of this work on the server side. This way the user only submits a query and the server sends information in response to their request. This will speed things up for the user and keep the keys from being accessed by other individuals.

Steps I think I need to take.

1. Set up server to access the API's
2. Make app access online server through HTTP requests
   3....
   4...

I have a very general concept in my head, but I'm not sure where to begin. If I'm wrong on any part of this question please correct me.

I do plan on moving this to the app store in the future.
**edit:** Do you know of tutorials that show the building of the API and then loading it to Amazon AWS or another server?

Comment: for school project there is good alternative - GAE (google application engine) which can host small applications for free and it works with Firebase out of the box. For small number of queries it's ideal. All sync work is on the Firebase side (db, sync, push msgs, analytics...), so you can focus on your app logic, not tools

Answer (score 1):

There are many options when building restful services for api consumption. You could start with php, which is the easiest to start with. Here is a nice tutorial that takes you through the initial stage all the way to the end of building login system for android using mysql and php as the server language. It contains the barebone details of setting up the infrastructure and logic. I think from there you manipulate and go further.

https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: seriously? how it easier for programmer, who knows java to start with php?!

Comment: php is really easy

Answer (score 0):

check out java rest easy, it is a nice tool to use to build web API's. You can host it for cheap at red shift or amazon using their pay what you use billing.

The cheapest way for you to host your REST API is to use Amazon's API Gateway. You pay for what you use and pay nothing if it is not being used. API Gateway plays very nicely with Amazon's Lambda service that allows you to run discrete code units - again, you only pay for what you use. Lambda itself plays nicely with Amazon's pay-as-you go NoSQL datastores (SimpleDB and DynamoDB).